# Touch event javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, canvas

I make a mobile game and want that the ball moves to the right when the user touch on the left side of the screen and if the user touch the screen on the right side the ball should move to the left. I found a code snippet and try to use it, but it dont works. Have anyone a tip for me to solve the problem?

```js
     window.onload = window.onresize = function() {
       var C = 1; // canvas width to viewport width ratio
       var W_TO_H = 2 / 1; // canvas width to canvas height ratio
       var el = document.getElementById("myCanvas");


       var viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
       var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;

       var canvasWidth = viewportWidth * C;
       var canvasHeight = canvasWidth / W_TO_H;
       el.style.position = "fixed";
       el.setAttribute("width", canvasWidth);
       el.setAttribute("height", canvasHeight);
       el.style.top = (viewportHeight - canvasHeight) / 2;
       el.style.left = (viewportWidth - canvasWidth) / 2;
       var x = canvasWidth / 100;
       var y = canvasHeight / 100;

       window.ctx = el.getContext("2d");
       ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
       // draw triangles
       ctx.beginPath();
       ctx.moveTo(x * 90, y * 50);
       ctx.lineTo(x * 99, y * 75);
       ctx.lineTo(x * 99, y * 25);
       ctx.closePath();
       ctx.stroke();
       ctx.beginPath();
       ctx.moveTo(x * 10, y * 50);
       ctx.lineTo(x * 1, y * 25);
       ctx.lineTo(x * 1, y * 75);
       ctx.closePath();
       ctx.stroke();

       ballx = canvasWidth / 100;
          
       // draw ball
       ctx.beginPath();
       ctx.fillStyle = "#FF4422"
       ctx.arc(ballx * 50, y * 50, x * 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
       ctx.fill();

       function init() {
         // Get a reference to our touch-sensitive element
         var touchzone = document.getElementById("gameArea");
         // Add an event handler for the touchstart event
         touchzone.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, false);
       }

       function touchHandler(event) {
         // Get a reference to our coordinates div
         var can = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
         // Write the coordinates of the touch to the div
         if (event.touches[0].pageX < x * 50) {
           ballx += x * 2;
         } else if (event.touches[0].pageY > x * 50) {
           ballx -= x * 2;
         }


       }
     }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div="gameArea">
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your HTML:

```
<div="gameArea">
```

should be:

```
<div id="gameArea">
```

The JS looks fine. Just don't forget to run your `init()` function at some point.

Another issue - setting the canvas position to fixed causes its parent element (the gameArea) not to expand to the canvas size. You either fix that in HTML, or simply listen for touches on the canvas itself (this makes more sense).

---

Next issue:

```
            if (event.pageX < x * 50) {
                ballx += 1;
            } else if (event.pageY > x * 50) {
                ballx -= 1;
            }
```

you need to check for pageX in both cases:

```
                } else if (event.pageX > x * 50) {
```

Also notice I've changed modifying the ballx by `x * 2` to modifying it by `1` because in your render function you already multiply it by `x`, so `x * x * 2` would cause the ball to render outside of the canvas.

---

Here is a slightly simplified version adjusted to work in browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/4hy12hyo/

That should be more than enough to get you started.